# How to convert a Python string to a dimensional array or list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have this string:

```
'(+ (- 5 4) (- 2 1))'
```

and I want it to convert it to an array/list so that the output of the string will be like this:

```
['+', ['-', 5, 4], ['-', 2, 1]]
```

The parentheses will be a new array inside the array as an element. This is kind of tricky to me since I'm new to this. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

if i try

```
'(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 4 5)))'
```

the output should be

```
['+', 1, ['+', 2, ['+', 4, 5]]]
```

Comment: Where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every object in the array will be a single character?

Comment: My code right now is not that helpful I'd say.

Comment: `eval(re.sub(r"([+\-*/])",r"'\1'",'(+ (- 5 4) (- 2 1))').replace(" ",","))` here's a really dirty one line solution.

Comment: @MihirSinghal , yes, every object in the array will be a single character

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse prefix (or "Polish") notation (maybe even LISP or Scheme code)? If you are, there's the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) to split the string with `(` or `)` then split the result again with space (`i.split()`) :

```
>>> import re
>>> new=[i.split() if re.search(r'\d',i) else i for i in [j for j in re.split(r'\(|\)',s) 
>>> [[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in j] if isinstance(j,list) else j for j in new]
['+ ', ['-', 5, 4], ['-', 2, 1]]
```

Demo:

```
>>> re.split(r'\(|\)',s)
['', '+ ', '- 5 4', ' ', '- 2 1', '', '']

>>>new= [i.split() if re.search(r'\d',i) else i for i in [j for j in re.split(r'\(|\)',s) if len(j.strip())]]
['+ ', ['-', '5', '4'], ['-', '2', '1']]
>>> [[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in j] if isinstance(j,list) else j for j in new]
['+ ', ['-', 5, 4], ['-', 2, 1]]
```

`i.strip()` is because of refuse from choose space !

Comment: But what if you don't want to have to run multiple times?

Comment: does not match the expected output

Comment: the numbers aren't `int`s and the leading `+` is in a list

Comment: @GP89 oops , thanks for reminding , imiss that , i will edit !

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kasra! It worked pretty good until i tried 
    '(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 4 5)))' 
the output will be:
    [['+', 1], ['+', 2], ['+', 4, 5]]
But the output I want is more like this:
    ['+', 1, ['+', 2, ['+', 4, 5]]] 
Its quite recursive.

Answer (score 0):

```
def interprettokens(tokens):
    ans = () # use a tuple at first so we don't get mutability problems.
    tokens = (tokens[0][1:],) + tokens[1:-1] + (tokens[-1][:-1],)
    while tokens != tuple():
        if tokens[0][0] != '(':
            ans += (tokens[0],)
            tokens = tokens[1:]
        else:
            if tokens[0][-1] == ')':
                ans += ([tokens[0][1:-1]],)
                tokens = tokens[1:]
            else:
                openParenCount = 1
                closeParenCount = 0
                index = 1
                while openParenCount != closeParenCount:
                    if tokens[index][0] == '(':
                        openParenCount += 1
                    if tokens[index][-1] == ')':
                        closeParenCount += 1
                    index += 1
                ans += (interprettokens(tokens[0:index]),)
                tokens = tokens[index:]
    return list(ans)


def interpret(string):
    tokens = tuple(string.split(' '))
    return interprettokens(tokens)
```

It's a bit long, but it works. Just run, for example, `interpret('(+ (- 5 4) (- 2 1))')` and it should work.